# Draw points in a view on iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

in my class I have an attribute `IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;` And if I want to draw an image in this view I do : `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];`
But how can I do to draw some points with coordinate x, y (in pixel) directly in the view ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView isn't designed to allow arbitrary drawing code. For this purpose, use a UIView and override the [`drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:) method.

Answer (score 0):

After you follow Marcelo's suggestion to draw in the view, you can pull the uiimage from the view with something like:

```
+(UIImage *)grabImageFromView: (UIView *) viewToGrab {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToGrab.bounds.size);

[[viewToGrab layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return viewImage;
}
```